# Clarifying volume symbol notation with a slash through it

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, notation, volume

I am reading Munson's book on Fluid Dynamics. One thing I found confusing was this notation in the image below, where the Volume has a slash or strikethrough through it. I am not clear about the meaning of that notation. Does it have something to do with intensive versus extensive properties from thermodynamics?

[image]

Can anyone clarify the reason for the slash throgh the volume symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munson uses a barred, italicized V to distinguish—when the context doesn't make it clear—volume from velocity, which is shown upright and in bold. (Subscripts referring to volume are italicized and in lowercase, as shown in your example.)

The barred V doesn't seem to indicate any special type of volume, as it's used throughout the text for control volumes, enclosure volumes, fluid volumes, and infinitesimal volumes, for instance.

Comment: Ohhh that makes a lot more sense. Phew, i was thinking it was a lot more complicated than it was. I had seen some notation similar to this in the Karder books on statistical physics, and that is why I thought it had a different meaning. But what you are saying is that the slash in the V helps to disambiguate between velocity and volume. Thanks so much.